# Thread execution inside loop with locks

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to write a program that will constantly run inside a loop and only run a thread if the previous thread has closed. I can't check the status of the thread outside of the first if statement because `status` is declared inside the first if statement. If I check the status inside the first statement, I get locked out completely. How can I implement something to get around this without making the thread join the main program?

```
    int script_lock = 1; //lock is open
    while (true) {

        if ( script_lock == 1) {
            script_lock = 0; //lock is closed 
            auto future = async (script, execute); //runs concurrently with main program
            auto status = future.wait_for(chrono::milliseconds(0));    
        }

        if (status == future_status::ready) { //status not declared in scope
            script_lock = 1; //lock is open
        }

        //do extra stuff
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just declare `status` right after `while` ?

Answer (score 0):

This code has an issue: if `script_lock` becomes equal to `0` and the first time `status == future_status::ready` fails, then `script_lock` will never change value.

You can simplify the code as follows:

```
bool finished = true;
while (true) {
    // Define future here

    if (finished){
        future = async (script, execute); 
        finished = false;  
    }

    if (future.wait_for(chrono::milliseconds(0)) == future_status::ready) 
          finished = true;

    //do extra stuff
}
```

Comment: `error: missing template arguments before ‘.’ token
     if (future.wait_for(chrono::milliseconds(0)) == future_status::ready)`

Comment: Yes, you have to figure out the full type for the future (no `auto` as it is defined prior than calling `async`) and add proper template arguments if needed.